# Java code completion in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide

A few years ago i set up my first Eclipse IDE env at work to begin studying the language. As i remember, it was some Luna build and it had a specific and really addictive code completion, which understood skipping some letters... like "p l n" would find "println".

Now i'w installed Mars build(the Luna's one has gone with the past harddrive), and cant find this option. Some code completion works, but it looks only by the current character.

Could someone tell me where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does understand skipping some letters in code complete, for example, if I have:

```java
System.out.pln
```

with my cursor after the `n` and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> I am presented with all the `println` choices:

[image]

If it is not working for you I suspect that you don't have [Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/) installed or enabled. It should come by default with [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars1).

To check to see if it is installed and enabled, in Preferences, choose *Java* -> *Editor* -> *Code Assist* -> *Advanced* and see if *Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)* is listed and checked:

[image]

If it is not installed, install it from the Mars update site:

1. From Help menu, choose *Install New Software*
2. Choose *Work With:* as *Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars .* from the drop-down list.
3. Choose *Code Recommenders for Java Developers* from the list. You may need to uncheck *Group items by category* to find it.

[image]

4. Complete the wizard, restart, check setting about and away you go.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse just press ctrl + space bar. to auto code completion