# Eclipse Contentassist full abbrev only

Tags: eclipse, code-completion, content-assist, camelcasing, abbreviation

When I like to create a new variable of type `ImageObserver` and the line starts like this:

```
IO
```

and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> , I get a couple of wrong suggestions! Suggestions for abbrevs that do not fully match!

Eclipse's content assist suggestions are:

- IOException (**no!** full abbrev is IOE, not IO!)
- IOError (**no!** full abbrev is IOE too, but not IO!)
- IndexOutOfBoundsException (**no!** full abbrev is IOOBE, not IO!)
- **ImageObserver** (**yes**! full abbrev is IO)
- ImageOutputStream (**no!** full abbrev is IOS, not IO!)

How to get rid of all the other non-full-matching-abbrevs?

Answer (score 1):

You really want `IOException` to be excluded on auto-complete when `IO` is typed even though `IOException` starts with `IO`?

If so, this sounds like a feature request, but unless you are ready to contribute I can't see it getting added anytime soon.

### Contributing

If you are interested in contributing, you need to write a [Java Completion Proposal Computer](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html?cp=3_1_1_25). Once you do that, you can enable only your proposer in the preferences (*Java* / *Editor* / *Content Assist* / *Advanced* ).

You can even bind your special completer to its own Keyboard Short-cut so you can get "full abbrev" completions only.

Here is a screenshot of my binding of Template Proposals to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> so with a single key combination I can get quickly get them all.

[image]

### Code Recommenders

I also recommend reading about [Code Recommenders](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/), the project adds significantly more sophisticated code completion to Eclipse.

I have raised a [bug with Eclipse](http://eclip.se/485475) to see if sorting perfect Camel Case matches could be on the cards.

Comment: I remember old eclipse 2 version they had this feature. Code recommenders is community driven afaik, the class is not widely used enougth to have `ImageObserver` resolved from `IO` by default.

Comment: ... and yes, i expect `ImageObserver` resolved from `IO`. And i expect `IOException` be proposed from `IOE`. Why the question?

Comment: Because what you are asking for is a significant subset of what auto-completion does and can do.

Comment: As for code recommenders, it adds much more than just community driven, it is also driven by you, plus it adds other more intelligent completions (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34565115/2796832). I am very impressed that you always remember the exact camel case abbreviation for every class you ever want to autocomplete, personally I can't remember if a class was called XmlParser or XMLParser (although I wish people would always have the ml lower case in Xml)

Comment: The rules for naming classes did not change in the last years. If the abrev is more widly used than the complete name it is upcase, so XMLParser have the abrev `XMLP` naturally. Seriously? I do not know the Abrevs, but i know the classes i am looking for. In example the FileNotFoundException leads me to write only FNFE, so only as a fallback other proposals should be appear.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the completion proposals fall into a bunch of categories (ie, lots of different sources of potential matches). Your example text, `IO`, can logically be interpreted as either a camel-case abbreviation (such as `ImageObserver`) *or* as the start of a class name (such as `IOException`), or even as a camel-case-starts-with match (such as `ImageOutputStream`, whose abbreviation starts with `IO`).

I don't know of a tool that's clairvoyant enough to know which of those you want given such a small input. Eclipse, by default, uses a "relevance" ordering for completion proposals and it weighs "starts with" matches ahead of camel-case matches (rightly so, in my opinion). There's no publicly exposed way to change that weighting algorithm, that I know of.

If these are classes or packages that you simply never want to see in Content-Assist, you can define Type Filters to exclude them. In **Preferences**, go to **Java** > **Appearance** > **Type Filters** to do so. But be aware that Type Filters apply to the entire workspace and in multiple places in the UI, not just Content Assist completion proposals.